# Laravel Eloquent seeder calculate number of row for each foreign key

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I want to count number of Services for each Site and insert the count into each row of Site record using Seeder. The system already has data in production, so I can't put 0 as default value for all Sites.

Here's my model declarations:

```
class Site extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $fillable = ['name', 'state', 'district', 'zone', 'coordinates'];

    public function states()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(State::class, 'state');
    }

    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class, 'district');
    }

    public function services()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Service');
    }
}

class Service extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $dates = ['date'];
    public $fillable = ['user_id', 'site_id', 'title', 'status', 'remarks', 'report', 'date'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\User');
    }

    public function site()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Site');
    }

    public function serviceItems() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\ServiceItem');
    }

}
```

Update:

```
class ServiceCounterSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $sites = Site::all();
        foreach($sites as $site){
            $site->service_counter = $site->services->count();
            $site->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by using:

```
class ServiceCounterSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $sites = Site::all();
        foreach($sites as $site){
            $site->service_counter = $site->services->where('status', ServiceStatus::DONE)->count(); // you can add custom filter WHERE here
            $site->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Inspired by @vahid's answer.
Don't forget to run the seeder using php artisan db:seed --class=[SeederName]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a seeder, and use this for every `site` object:

```
$site->services()->count();
```

Comment: Can you share further details on implementing this? Thanks!

Comment: you want to know, each site has how many services? 
so, in your seeder for every site that you have in your DB, write the code above.
try this and see the result.

Comment: Do you mean I have to write separate seeder for every site? Because that doesn't make sense when there is few hundreds of sites. Can you explain further by showing some codes? Thanks

Comment: no no, you have a `Site` model, you have access to every site that you want. like this:

```
$sites = Site::all();
```

Comment: How does `$sites = Site::all();`  works with `$site->services()->count();`?

Comment: `$sites = Site::all();`
`foreach($sites as $site){
     $result[$site->id] = $site->services()->count();
}`